# How can I cover a div completely with an image?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a div with content inside, but I'd like to cover that content completely with an image that is on top of everything else.

I'm using bootstrap if that helps

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div> I have images and paragraphs inside of me </div>
  <div> I have images and paragraphs inside of me </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I tried setting a background image to the jumbotron, but that put the image behind everything else, instead of on top. I tried a few other things, but everything messed up the existing layout that should exist underneath the covering image.

Comment: like styling `background-image` of said div, or are you thinking to cover to HIDE the contents of DIV?

Comment: May I ask why you want the content there but not visible?

Comment: If you want the image to be on top, you should use a img with alt text
Background is a BACK ground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You could position the image absolutely to cover the text.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/3TFvr/)

```
.jumbotron{
    position: relative;
}
.jumbotron img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

[You could also use a background image in this situation as well if your text is way too large. This is kind of goofy but the requirements here are kind of goofy:](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Gyk33/4/)

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.jumbotron img {
    position: absolute;
}
.jumbotron .covering{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: What happens if his text and images are larger than the image? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Gyk33/

Comment: I would do this the other way round so the image is relative and the text is absolute - that way the div will take the space of the image rather than the text

Comment: Instead of an image you could use a div using a background. Both parent and child would have to use width / height: 100%; http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Gyk33/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the same CSS positioning and sizing rules to both the image and the text and make the z-index of the image higher than the text.